# Compare data of each line from file1 to data from file 2

Tags: java, performance, java-8

I have two large txt files around 150 mb. I want to read some data from each line of file1 and scan through all the lines of file2 till I find the matching data. If the matching data is not found, I want to output that line to another file.

I want the program to use as less memory as possible. Time is not a constraint.

## Edit1

I have tried couple of options

Option1 : I have read the file2 using BufferedReader, Scanner and apache commons  FileUtils.lineIterator. Loaded data of file2 into HashMap by reading each line. Read the data from file1 one line at a time  and compared with data in HashMap. If it didn't match, wrote the line in a file3.

Option 2 : Read the file2 n times for every records in File 1 using the above mentioned three Readers.After every  read I had to close the file and read again.  I am wondering what's the best way. Is there any other option I can look into

Comment: It's an interesting question, but what have you tried so far, and what did you find by doing your own research?

Comment: Use `BufferedReader` to read the contents of the `File` and then compare them in the manner you want.

Comment: @Abs Excellent, can you update your question to show us what you have tried, and then we can further help where you are getting stuck. There are a number of ways to achieve this (Scanner, BufferedReader), but by seeing what you have tried we can make better suggestions.

Comment: If you are ok with very minimal error, i'm thinking you can use option 1 , rather than storing line by line in hashmap , you can use md5 hash..

Comment: @aravind Very good idea, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make some assumptions about the file.
I am going to assume the lines are long, and you want the lines that are not the same in the 2 files.

I would read the files 4 times (2 times per file).
Of course, it's not as efficient as reading it 2 times (1 time per file), but reading it 2 times means lots of memory is used.

Pseudo code for 1st read of each file:

```
Map<MyComparableByteArray, Long> digestMap = new HashMap<>();
try (BufferedReader br = ...)
{
    long lineNr = 0;
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        digestMap.put(CreateDigest(line), lineNr);
    }
}
```

If the digests are different/unique, I know that the line does not occur in the other file.
If the digests are the same, we will need to check the lines and actually compare them to make sure that they are really the same - this can occur during the second read.

Now what is also important is that we need to be careful of the digest we choose.
If we choose a short digest (i.e. md-5), we might run into lots of collisions, but this is appropriate for files with short lines, and we will need to handle the collisions separately (i.e. convert the map to a map<digest, list> structure.

If we choose a long digest (i.e. sha2-512), we won't run into lots of collisions (still safer to handle it like I mentioned above), BUT we will have the problem of not saving as much memory unless the file lines are very long.

So the general technique is:

1. Read each file and generate hashes.
2. Compare the hashes to mark the lines that need to be compared.
3. Read each file again and generate the output.  Recheck all collisions found by the hashes in this step.

By the way, MyComparableByteArray is a custom wrapper around a byte[], to enable it to be a HashMap key (i.e. by implementing equals() and hashCode() methods).  The byte[] cannot be used as a key, as it doesn't work with equals() and hashCode().  There are 2 ways to handle this:

1. custom wrapper as I've mentioned - this will be more efficient than the alternative.
2. convert it to a string using base64.  This will make the memory usage around 2.5x worse than option 1, but does not need the custom code.